# Is explicit CROSS JOIN possible with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to generate an explicit CROSS JOIN query with SQLAlchemy as the following example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
CROSS JOIN bar
```

And if yes, how?

I would guess something similar to this

```
session.query(Foo).crossjoin(Bar).all()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can make cartesian product using inner join,
applying condition which is always true.
E.g. for SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal

session.query(Foo, Bar).join(Bar, literal(True)).all()
```

There're only `join` and `outerjoin` functions in SQLAlchemy for now (v0.9).

Comment: Note that the explicit join on a `literal(True)` doesn't work under SQL Alchemy 1.3 now (throws an error requesting an ON clause), though the concept outlined by @vvladymyrov still works (essentially `session.query(Foo, Bar).all()`).

Answer (score 3):

SQLAlchemy doesn't have explicit way to specify CROSS JOIN.
IMHO all major relation databases do CROSS JOIN when you has tables in FROM clause, but no join criteria between them.

I would suggest to use SQL Expression API and not SQLAlchemy ORM API for tasks like that - so you'll get resulting records and otherwise SQLAlchemy ORM API will try to do object mapping. For your example I assume that Foo and Bar are mapped classes:

```
connection.execute(select[Foo.__table__,Bar.__table__])
```

Please see [example from the SQLAlchemy manual](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html?highlight=cartesian%20product#selecting) describing how to make query generate Cartesian product; each row from the users table is produced against each row from the addresses table:

```
>>> for row in conn.execute(select([users, addresses])):
...     print row  
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.fullname, addresses.id, addresses.user_id, addresses.email_address
FROM users, addresses
()
```