# sqlalchemy create a list of integers as a subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, union

I have a query that requires me to join on a span of years like 2012, 2013 and 2014. All years are required to return rows even if there are no values for the year. In SQL this would look something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    kpi.unit_type_row_model
CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT 2012 AS Year UNION ALL SELECT 2013 UNION ALL SELECT 2014 ) AS Y

    -- MORE JOINS FOR GETTING VALUES
```

How do I create a subquery of:

```
SELECT 2012 AS Year UNION ALL SELECT 2013 UNION ALL SELECT 2014
```

2012, 2013 and 2014 are sent in values and the union has to be created on the fly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but... have you seen the subquery method in SqlAlchemy? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries (probably you have, but dunno... it may give you some ideas? Maybe? )

Comment: yeah, I know about the subquery. I need to create one from a list of, in this case, integers.

Comment: Would you mind posting how that SQL query is generated or used? I mean... Do you want it to be just an string that you compile as a query using sqlalchemy or is it done through sqlalchemy ORM capabilities that generates that SQL underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As pointed out in answer for [Is explicit CROSS JOIN possible with SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813516/is-explicit-cross-join-possible-with-sqlalchemy), there is no explicit `CROSS JOIN` in `sqlalchemy`. Similar effect is received by simply selecting from both (or more) tables without any `join` condition at all.
2. To get second select, simply use [`text`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct.

Combining both together, here is the solution:

```
years = range(2012, 2016)
txt = " UNION ALL ".join("SELECT {} AS Year".format(y) for y in years)
stmt = text(txt).columns(Year=Integer) # @note: works only on sqlachemy >= 0.9
# stmt = text(txt, typemap={'Year': Integer}) # note: fall back for SA version < 0.9
q = session.query(MyClass, stmt) # @note: since there is no JOIN, it will return cartesian product
for row in q.all():
    print(row)
```

Comment: will this work on all rdbms sqlalchemy supports? How do I get the year out in the select or that's why you're adding a column? The cross join I managed to figure out by reading the post you mentioned and a few more. Thanks for that.

Comment: I get an error on `stmt = text(txt).columns(Year=Integer)`. `AttributeError: "'TextClause' object has no attribute 'columns'"`

Comment: OK, this works only since sqlalchemy version>=0.9. If you have older version, then use `stmt = text(txt, typemap={'Year': Integer})` instead

Comment: I can't set as the answer unless the solution is supported on all rdbms sqlalchemy supports. If not I could just have created a text query to start with.

Comment: 1) it is not a problem with RDBMS, but rather newer version of sqlalchemy supports cleaner way of doing things; 2) you are right: text query sounds like a much cleaner and cross platform solution. 3) please share your final solution so that we can also learn from it. 4) Thank you.

Comment: :) great I could help :)